# UiAutomator - How to know if an object is present at certain coordinates

Tags: android-uiautomator

I want to know if it is possible to determine using UiAutomator APIs if there is a widget at certain coordinates (like (100, 100) for example) on the home screen of Android device.

Is there any existing method that can help me determine this?

Comment: you can create uiobject and take `getbounds()` and check the cordinates are same as which yor are checking for

Answer (score -1):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) implements `ViewClient.findViewsContainingPoint()` which returns the list of Views that contain a specified point.

Using `culebra` to generate a script and adding this call at the end to find the Views at `(544, 567)` gives you something like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2016  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2016-07-19 by Culebra v11.5.9
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

TAG = 'CULEBRA'

_s = 5
_v = '--verbose' in sys.argv


kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)
vc.dump()
print vc.findViewsContainingPoint((544,567))
```

If you want to implement it in Java using UiAutomator just copy the implementation as everything can be reproduced more or less the same.